# turn nested rows of text file into dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like that:

```
INFO  : org.apache.tez.common.counters.DAGCounter:
INFO  :    NUM_SUCCEEDED_TASKS: 58
INFO  :    TOTAL_LAUNCHED_TASKS: 58
INFO  :    DATA_LOCAL_TASKS: 26
INFO  : File System Counters:
INFO  :    FILE_BYTES_READ: 954341
INFO  :    FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN: 207491
INFO  : org.apache.tez.common.counters.TaskCounter:
INFO  :    REDUCE_INPUT_GROUPS: 1200
.
.
.
INFO  : TaskCounter_Reducer_2_OUTPUT_out_Reducer_2:
INFO  :    OUTPUT_RECORDS: 0
INFO  : org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveInputCounters:
INFO  :    GROUPED_INPUT_SPLITS_Map_1: 13
INFO  :    GROUPED_INPUT_SPLITS_Map_3: 10
INFO  : Completed executing command...
```

(the vertical dots included are there to symbolise that are a lot more lines going on in between)
What I want to do is to be able to get those lines from the file (that I have already stored in memory with the code provided below), take advantage of their indentation (which I noticed is **not** tab-based), and deliver a dictionary like that:

```
{
"org.apache.tez.common.counters.DAGCounter" : {"NUM_SUCCEEDED_TASKS": 58 , "TOTAL_LAUNCHED_TASKS" : 58 , ...} ,
"File System Counters:" : { ... } ,
 .
 .
 .
"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveInputCounters" : { ... }
}
```

This is the code I've been using to parse the text file and load the lines into an array, and that's my preferred way of loading the lines at this point since memory isn't a problem.

```
DM={}
lines = []
with open(txt,'r') as txt:
    for line in txt:
        lines.append(line)
```

The `DM` dictionary is where I want to save my output.

Comment: You can use regex.

Comment: You may find this library helpful: https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. I only did `if` with `elif` to show you how to build these patterns. If the data is always the same (like intendation of 1 as key of indendation of 4 for nested key-value) then you can just check with for one space in the `if` statement, and everything else will be in the `else` part.

```
dic = {}
for line in data:
    if re.search(r"^INFO\s+:\s\w",line):
        key = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        dic[key] = {}
    elif re.search(r"INFO\s+:\s{3,5}\w", line): #e.g it would accept 3 to 5 spaces here 
        k, v = line.split(':')[1:]
        dic[key][k.strip()] = int(v)
    else: 
        print('different format')
print(dic)

{'org.apache.tez.common.counters.DAGCounter': 
          {'NUM_SUCCEEDED_TASKS': 58, 
           'TOTAL_LAUNCHED_TASKS': 58, 
           'DATA_LOCAL_TASKS': 26}, 
  'File System Counters': 
          {'FILE_BYTES_READ': 954341, 
           'FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN': 207491}, 
  'org.apache.tez.common.counters.TaskCounter': 
          {'REDUCE_INPUT_GROUPS': 1200}}
```

I just used the data above your 3 vertical dots.